# How to print from an iPad app without the use of AirPrint?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, printing, airprint

I am developing an iPad application where in there is a requirement that application should be able to print using any WiFi Printer even though it does not support AirPrint.

I need to do it without the use of AirPrint and AirPrint Hactivator.

I have referred to almost all questions on StackOverflow but none did seem to help.

I have seen a sample application which is on app store and which implements this.

[Printing for iPad By Ndili Technologies, Inc.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/printing-for-ipad/id397734760?mt=8)

What are my options to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: The reviews for that app are not encouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this API/SDK, which I haven't used, but looks promising :

http://www.e-workshop-dev.com/PC_EN/develop_title_e.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way of doing this. As far as I know Apple will not let you install printer drivers on the iDevice. And even if you could you would have to get all of them yourself (there are a lot and you would likely miss some). And then you would have to find a way to implement all of them so that they would work. If you have found a way to do this, then kudos to you, but I do not know of any App Store developer that has accomplished this yet, and I doubt it is possible.

Comment: Check the iTunes Link in my question..! I think it does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could develop some sort of system that relies on connecting to a service on computer that has a printer. When apple originally Released the beta of AirPrint you could send a print to iTunes and then it would send it to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

The Print n Share Pro ([product page](http://mobile.eurosmartz.com/products/printnsharepro.html), [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/app/pns/id471352087?ls=1)) app has drivers for most WiFi printers and print email/webpages & files etc. direct without a computer. They also have an API to allow other apps to print using their app but you will need to contact them about that.